# Does immutable data "burn up" RAM in D?

Tags: concurrency, d, immutability

Consider a worker loop that has something like:

```
...
auto msg = new immutable(DataWrittenMsg)(bytesWritten);
masterTid.send(msg);
...
```

Will this slowly but surely eat up all RAM, as time reaches Inf? Or can unused immutable data get collected by the GC?

(I'm reading [TDPL Ch. 13](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1609144) and I get the impression once immutable data is set it can never get unset?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, the GC will still pick up unreferenced objects, regardless of their constness.

Regarding "once immutable data is set it can never get unset" - this is only so in the logical sense. Assuming your program's memory safety isn't compromised, all immutable heap-allocated objects your program has access to will not change for as long as they're reachable, even though the actual memory at that address can be reused once those objects become unreachable.